# LINQ to SQL - Two tables, same name? or Alternate DB definition?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I need to update a C# application that imports data into a database using LINQ. I am new to LINQ. The problem I am trying to solve is that there are two versions of the DB. They have the same table names and are 90% identical in structure, but have one table (out of about 60) which has a different definition.

If LINQ were not involved, I would simply select a different query depending on which version of the application (DB) the user wanted to import to, and leave the remainder of the application as is.

My impression is that LINQ is intended for situations in which the DB structure is cast in stone, and that I cannot have two LINQ table definitions having the same name and simply or easily switch between them (or do so at all).

In this case, must I have (at least) a separate entire Linq.DataContext for each version of the DB? Or have I misunderstood something basic here?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to make that happen using separate mappings. In this case you would have to hand code your mappings as apposed to the attribute-based mapping that the LINQ designer or SqlMetal does for you. I've never done it, but I think it might work. I just googled for "Linq to Sql POCO mapping" and found this: [Achieving POCO s in Linq to SQL](http://www.sidarok.com/web/blog/content/2008/10/14/achieving-poco-s-in-linq-to-sql.html). This person is loading his mapping from an xml file at runtime. You could conditionally load one of two different mapping files.

Comment: This looked promising, but 1) it will still essentially duplicate the entire DB structure, 2) it exposes the DB structure in a human readable / mess-up-able text file, and 3) most importantly, apparently I still need to define the datacontext & structures, and these then conflict. I looked into having alternate predefined datacontexts that I could switch between, but this appears to be a non-starter. I have just recompiled this app as a separate version for the new DB structure. Not elegant, but neither would it be a particular burden to these specific users. And it's done.